# C# LINQ subquery (On entities)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to use LINQ to query a list of objects wherever appropriate. Currently I am stuck on the syntax of a nested query which I hope you can help me with.

Classes:

```
public class FooType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IList<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

}

public class Foo
{
    public int FooTypeId { get; set; }

    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string FooCorrelationId { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
IList < FooType > fooTypes = new List < FooType >();
// ... add a lot of FooTypes, each enriched with some Foos
Bar bar = new Bar(){FooCorrelationId = "abcdef"};
Foo foo = fooTypes.Where( ft => ft.Foos.Where( f => f.CorrelationId == bar.FooCorrelationId ) ).First<Foo>();
```

This fails because the outer WHERE-expression is fed with something that does not provide a boolean return value. As you might guess, I intend to something like the following in LINQ:

```
 foreach (FooType fooType in fooTypes)
 {
     Foo foo = fooType.Foos
                      .Where(f => f.CorrelationId == bar.FooCorrelationId)
                      .First();
 }
```

Do you have any idea how to get that Foo I'm looking for, the one with CorrelationId "abcdef"?

And one more question for the benchmarkers : What about performance? Does LINQ optimize it's queries? Or is the result the same as an iteration over the objects like I did in my "something like" block?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace the outer where with a SelectMany and get the first

```
Foo foo = fooTypes
    .SelectMany(ft => ft.Foos.Where(f => f.CorrelationId == bar.FooCorrelationId))
    .First();
```

If you an to get the first Foo across all FooType, what has CorrelationId == FooCorrelationId.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was just what I was looking for! I'll have to take a little timeout to improve my linq skills =)